# Get partial results in Postgres in case of timeout?

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to send a query that does a sequential scan of the table - something like

```
SELECT content
  FROM some_big_table
 WHERE <some criteria(content) are met>;
 LIMIT <...>;
```

with a time limit (e. g. 1000 milliseconds) - so that the query terminates after the specified time period and returns any rows it could find by that time as a result of the scan?

I'm not worried about the result being predictable - I just need to give the user the first matches the server can find, if any.

`SET statement_timeout` does not help here as it cancels the query altogether if it doesn't execute within the time limit, while I need the partial results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to do exactly what you want, making a query end normally on the server based on a time limit rather than a row LIMIT.  You could declare a cursor and then FETCH rows in chunks (perhaps chunks of 1), closing the cursor after a certain amount of time has passed as witnessed on the client. Depending on the driver you are using, there may be other options to get similar results, such as [PQsetSingleRowMode in libpq](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-single-row-mode.html).